# How to install g++-4.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, g++, package, debian

There is no `g++-4.7` with `apt-get install`, all `g++` versions provided by `apt-get` are equal to or under 4.6, so how can I install `g++-4.7`?

Comment: do this: `$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7`

Comment: btw you are answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76885/where-can-i-find-a-g-4-7-package and http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the g++ 4.7 deb package from web. then install it by using dpkg